# PHP $_GET and underlines

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a very short piece of PHP that I use to make HTTP requests from JavaScript.

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>
```

I have used it successfully in a few projects, but am running into a problem with making requests in my current project. Based on my searching, I believe it may be caused by the underscore in the request, though through my searching and not knowing PHP, I have not been able to confirm that.

Below is an example of what I am doing from JavaScript:

```
$.get("grabber.php?url=" + "http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/datagetter?station=8573364&begin_date=20160202&end_date=20160203&product=predictions&units=english&time_zone=gmt&format=json&application=poseidonweathercom+&datum=MLLW", function(forecast) {

    console.log(forecast);

});
```

If I copy the url and put in it in a browser, I get back the JSON that I requested. When I use the code above, I end up getting an error message from NOAA:

> Wrong Product : Product cannot be null or empty  Wrong Time zone: Time zone cannot be null or empty  Wrong Unit:Unit cannot be null or empty   Wrong Format: Format cannot be null or empty  Wrong Date: The beginDate cannot be null or empty

Do I need to use a regex for the underscore in PHP? Is there some other issue that I do not understand?

Thanks.

Comment: The value of url is a parameter, and it should be encoded as such.  Try `$.get("grabber.php?url=" + encodeURIComponent(stringContainingURL), ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send it encoded, which will convert all the underscores/spaces/ampersands etc. with their encoded equivalents:

```
var url = "http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/datagetter?station=8573364&begin_date=20160202&end_date=20160203&product=predictions&units=english&time_zone=gmt&format=json&application=poseidonweathercom+&datum=MLLW";

$.get("grabber.php?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url), function(forecast){
    console.log(forecast);
}
```

Using `encodeURIComponent()` on that URL shows:

```
http%3A%2F%2Ftidesandcurrents.noaa.gov%2Fapi%2Fdatagetter%3Fstation%3D8573364%26begin_date%3D20160202%26end_date%3D20160203%26product%3Dpredictions%26units%3Denglish%26time_zone%3Dgmt%26format%3Djson%26application%3Dposeidonweathercom%2B%26datum%3DMLLW
```

---

**Alternatively**, if you just want to access the JSON data and handle it within the JavaScript function, you can retrieve the data via the URL directly, without having to encode the URL:

```
$.get("http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/datagetter?station=8573364&begin_date=20160202&end_date=20160203&product=predictions&units=english&time_zone=gmt&format=json&application=poseidonweathercom+&datum=MLLW", function(forecast) {
    console.log(forecast);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ben. That is great stuff.

Comment: No worries at all mate.

Answer (score 0):

Um why do you even need your php code ... the code below will work just fine and eliminate your server overhead.

```
$.get("http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/datagetter?station=8573364&begin_date=20160202&end_date=20160203&product=predictions&units=english&time_zone=gmt&format=json&application=poseidonweathercom+&datum=MLLW", function(forecast) {

    console.log(forecast);

});
```

Comment: This isn't helpful if he wants his *`PHP`* page `grabber.php` to handle the data and output something other than just JSON.